# selecting rows based on date

Tags: mysql

i have two tables, tasks and actions. actions has two columns, created_at and updated_at. tasks has a column started_at

how can i do something like

```
SELECT MAX( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( tasks.started_at ) ) AS started_at, action . * 
FROM tasks, action
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP( action.created_at ) > started_at
OR UNIX_TIMESTAMP( action.updated_at ) > started_at
```

trying to select all actions that have a greater created_at or updated_at than the MAX(tasks.started_at)

Comment: Is `started_at` a of `TIMESTAMP` format? Then just avoid using functions within `WHERE` clause, compare timestamps directly and change `MAX( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( tasks.started_at ) )` into `UNIX_TIMESTAMP( MAX( tasks.started_at ) )`.

Comment: `started_at` is `DATETIME`, not `TIMESTAMP`. what do you mean compare directly?

Comment: I meant that you can compare `TIMESTAMP` values (as well as `DATETIME`, but comparing across different date/time types may become tricky due to time zone issues) directly, without the need to convert them to Unix epoch. You can also get the highest and lowest values from `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns using `MAX()` and without the need to convert them to Unix epoch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM actions 
WHERE created_at>(SELECT MAX(started_at) FROM tasks) OR
      updated_at>(SELECT MAX(started_at) FROM tasks)
```

Don't worry about performance, by default MySQL should cache `SELECT MAX(started_at) FROM tasks` value. If you have other configuration add `SQL_CACHE` to main query: `SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM...`